# Running Windows 8.1 with defective ram

Tags: windows-8, memory

I had a defective ram stick and I don't have money  to get a new one yet.
The bad memory sector is somewhere between 2.4GB and 2.6GB. I was using linux but now i dual boot with windows 8.1 because I wanna play The Sims 4. I can't install TS4 because i had bad ram. Is there any way to block a bad ram sector? Using Windows BCD? and what i have to put in? I also have an integrated GPU so it will also eat ram.

EDIT: i have heard about bcdedit /set badmemorylist ??? ??? 
what i have to put in?

Comment: You're looking for a Windows equivalent to the [Linux `memmap` kernel parameter](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75059), which disables a specific memory region.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the RAM is bad, you need to remove it.  At best, you will have random reboots and lockups, at worst you can lose important data.